# sh variable not working if blank

Tags: bash, sh

Need some extra eyes for this one...

```
dns_lookup() {
    ip_set
    if [ `ip_ping ${ip_address}` -eq 0 ]
    then
            host=""
            dig +short -x ${ip_address} | sed 's/\.$//g' | while read host
            do
                    if [ -z "${host}" ]
                    then
                            host="unknown"
                    fi
                    echo "${ip_address},${host}"
            done
    fi
```

}

I get desired results if ip is pingable and has a dns name.  I do not get results if the ip is pingable but does not have a dns name.

---

```
ip_set() {
        ip_address="${a}.${b}.${c}.${d}"
}

ip_ping() {
  timeout ${delay} ping -q -c 1 -i 1 -W 1 -w 4 $1 > /dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?
}
```

---

Comment: What are `ip_set` and `ip_ping`? What is the value of `$ip_address`? What *exactly* does "do not get results" mean?

Answer (score 0):

You don't get a result when there's no hostname because your `while read` loop never runs when there are no lines to read. You should make your printing code run regardless:

```
host=$(dig +short -x "${ip_address}" | sed 's/\.$//g')
if [ -z "${host}" ]
then
    host="unknown"
fi
printf "${ip_address},%s\n" $host
```

Also, you're going about your condition wrong. You shouldn't echo the exit status and compare it as text. You should just let your command's exit status be your function's exit status:

```
ip_ping() {
  timeout ${delay} ping -q -c 1 -i 1 -W 1 -w 4 $1 > /dev/null 2>&1 
  # functions implicitly 'return $?' if you don't specify anything else
}
```

Now you can easily check your function:

```
if ip_ping "$ip_address"
then
    echo "It worked"
else
    echo "It failed.."
fi
```

Comment: In your example how is host defined if the host is true?  I get a list of all hosts unknown.

Comment: Ok, that works.  Maybe I did not explain myself properly.  I only want results dns or not if the ip responds to ping.  I get a full list.  My orginal code just listed ip's that responded to ping.

Comment: You want a list of N hostnames when the query succeeds and 1 line with hostname="unknown" when it doesn't? I updated it for that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you need. Tell me if you need revisions.

```
dns_lookup() {
    ip_set
    if [ `ip_ping ${ip_address}` -eq 0 ]
    then
        host=""
        dig +short -x ${ip_address} | sed 's/\.$//g' | {
            hashosts=false
            while read host
            do
                if [ -n "${host}" ]
                then
                    hashosts=true
                    echo "${ip_address},${host}"
                fi
            done
            [ "${hashosts}" = false ] && echo "${ip_address},unknown"
        }
    fi
}
```

I would have also suggested the change of function ip_ping but that_other_guy already did it.